# Multi user minting

Tags: erc-20

Can a smart contract issue coins continuously to all users who have submitted an ether wallet address to the issuer? And is there a way to add to that list over time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but those tokens wouldn't be minted automatically. The user (or an admin) would have to claim them at some point by executing a transaction on the smart contract.

The steps involved would be:

1. User signs up by calling a function that stores their address and time of sign up.
2. As time passes, tokens "accumulate" for those addresses that signed up
3. At any moment (or after some predefined time period) the users can call a function on the contract that calculates how many tokens they accrued based on the time passed since they signed up or since their last withdraw.
4. The user withdraws those tokens to their account (they get transferred).
5. They can repeat these steps as much as they want until there are no more tokens for them to mint/withdraw.